# Locating a question on zero-one vectors in the kernel of a matrix

Tags: discussion

I remember there was a question posted to MO about maybe two months ago or so which was, essentially, about the existence of zero-one vectors in the kernel of some matrix. Can anybody help me to locate that question? Thanks in advance!

(I think I have never posted to the MO Meta before; hope the question / request above fits the scope.)

Comment: Your question is fine; others have made similar requests at meta.

Comment: @Todd: Maybe it's worth having one thread for these type of requests.